# Use reticulate to call Python script and send email

Tags: python, r, rstudio, smtplib, reticulate

I use Windows Task Scheduler to run an R Script several times a day. The script transforms some new data and adds it to an existing data file.

I want to use `reticulate` to call a Python script that will send me an email listing how many rows of data were added, and if any errors occurred. This works correctly when I run it line by line from within RStudio. The problem is that it doesn't work when the script runs on schedule. I get the following errors:

```
Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : 
  Unable to open file 'setup_smtp.py' (does it exist?)
Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
  AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'message'
Calls: paste0 ... py_get_attr_or_item -> py_get_attr -> py_get_attr_impl
Execution halted
```

This github answer https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/232) makes it sound like `reticulate` can only be used within RStudio - at least for what I'm trying to do. Does anyone have suggestions?

Sample R script:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reticulate)
library(lubridate)

n_rows <- 10
time_raw <- now()

result <- paste0("\nAdded ", n_rows, 
                 " rows to data file at ", time_raw, ".")

try(source_python("setup_smtp.py"))

message_final <- paste0(py$message, result)

try(smtpObj$sendmail(my_email, my_email, message_final))
try(smtpObj$quit())
```

The Python script ("setup_smtp.py") is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Call from reticulate to log in to email
"""

import smtplib

my_email = '...'
my_password = '...'

smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.login(my_email, my_password)

message = """From: My Name <email address>
To: My Name <email address>
Subject: Test successful!
"""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This execution problem

> This works correctly when I run it line by line from within RStudio. The problem is that it doesn't work when the script runs on schedule

can stem from multiple reasons:

1. [image: Multiple Pythons]

   You have multiple Python versions where `smtplib` is installed on one version (e.g., Python 2.7 or Python 3.6) and not the other. Check which Python is being used at command line, `Rscript -e "print(Sys.which("python"))"` and RStudio, `Sys.which("python")`. Explicitly define which Python.exe to run with reticulate's `use_python("/path/to/python")`.

---

2. [image: Multiple Rs]

   You have multiple R versions where Rscript uses a different version than RStudio. Check `R.home()` variable in both: `Rscript -e "print(R.home())"` and call `R.home()` in RStudio. Explicitly call the required Rscript in appropriate R version bin folder: `/path/to/R #.#/bin/Rscript "/path/to/code.R"`.

---

3. [image: Multiple Reticulates]

   You have multiple `reticulate` packages installed on same R version, residing in different library locations, each calling a different Python version. Check with the matrix: `installed.package()`, locating the `reticulate` row. Explicitly call `library(reticulate, lib.loc="/path/to/specific/library")`.

Comment: Thanks Parfait! I will try all those solutions and report what works. PS See you at the next CRUG or ChiPy.

Comment: Haha! Glad to help, fellow Chicagoan!

Comment: It turns out, I just needed to use the absolute file path to the python script: source_python("C:/My_Folders/.../setup_smtp.py"). Rookie mistake! Thanks again for the detailed troubleshooting though, for when I have a REAL problem :)